# Webtoffee import products plugins

Tags: javascript

when i importing products through csv inconded utf-8 WEBTOFFEE plugins show me error every time that is

> An unknown error has occurred! Refer to our troubleshooting guide for
> assistance. You may also try increasing maximum execution time in
> advanced settings.

and webtoffee plugins not helping me even this plugins is paid plugins for wordpress
even my hosting 's exauction timit is high that is enough for importing but webtoffee's this plugins show me error that i mention above.is anyone who help me regarding this issue.

[webtoffee error screenshotis here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltXxy.png) .I also attacht the csv file which is upload by us ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A0hZzMxlh8hTYMr4nNu3Zo388HKdKx4o/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: As always srat with a small number of rows in the csv and pay with the settings.  alook in the csv will show you how fields a seperated and if crlf or lf characterizes a new line.

Comment: Your CSV URL says, Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.

Comment: @LALJI KRAFTS Have you sorted this out.?